# How to convert Single Dimension array into a column vector in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, vector

I want a column vector as my output but instead getting a single dimension array. Please check the code in the fiddle. What have I done wrong?

My Current and Expected output are:

**Current Output:** Array `[ 0, 1 ]` Array `[ 5, 10 ]`

**Expected Output:** Array `[ 0 ]` Array `[ 1 ]` Array `[ 5 ]` Array `[ 10 ]`

Please check **Browser Console.**

How can I get my Expected Output?

Js Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4o1dj1uw/2/

Code:

```
this.b = [[[0,1]],[[5,10]]];
function convertarray(arrToConvert) {
   //it will convert a matrix in array
   var newArr = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < arrToConvert.length; i++) {
        newArr = newArr.concat(arrToConvert[i]);
   }
   return newArr;
 }

console.log(...convertarray(this.b))
```

Comment: Just put it twice through `convertarray()`: `console.log(convertarray(convertarray(this.b)))` I'm not sure if that's what you want, but the result is one array

Comment: Is this a one time thing or do you see yourself doing this multiple times throughout the code?

Comment: Thank you! 
the array in this.b is actually inputted by the user. So I need individual array of all elements given as input. This needs to happen only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push it twice through `convertarray()`:

```
console.log(convertarray(convertarray(this.b)))
```

If you want to get an array of each item of these you can do:

```
console.log(...convertarray(convertarray(this.b)).map(x => [x]));
```

Result

```
[0] [1] [5] [10]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Highmastdon 
this method worked for me. Actually in my code [0,1] and [5,10 ]is given by user so suppose if he only enters an integer instead of an array, will this code still work?

Comment: If he only passes integers you have not the second dimension in the array. Therefore you wouldn't need to do it twice. You'd have to check wether the array is three-dimensional. Could be done something like this: `Array.isArray(arrToConvert[0][0])`. When this is true you have the three dimensional array, otherwise a two dimensional one.

Answer (score 2):

Almost there, you need to enter to the deepest array.

*An alternative is using recursion.*

```js
this.b = [[[0,1]],[[5,10]]];
function convertarray(arrToConvert) {
   //it will convert a matrix in array
   var newArr = [];
   for (var i = 0; i < arrToConvert.length; i++) {
        if (Array.isArray(arrToConvert[i])) {
          newArr = newArr.concat(convertarray(arrToConvert[i]));
        } else {
          newArr.push([arrToConvert[i]]);
        }
   }
   return newArr;
 }

console.log(JSON.stringify(convertarray(this.b)))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi @Ele Recursion is a good idea but this would not give me an array for every element in this.b right?